# Magento CSV upload - Products not uploaded all time

Tags: php, magento

I am uploading products using csv file in magento. Few times the product get uploaded. While other times it shows that all products imported but do not show under manage products options.

When the products are not coming even then I am not getting error while uploading csv.

Also I have added new fields in the csv file. But when I export the same its does not shows any data in it. Can any one help me out.

Comment: compare both products rows : 1) which uploaded and 2) which didt uploaded......

Comment: I have done the same. Both are completely same.

Comment: make sure you have different sku, also are you using magmi to upload ?

Comment: Ya all the products are having different skus